# Passing Parameters into ./configure

Tags: c, bash, gcc, makefile, configure

For whatever reason, the third party drivers I'm using need to have `-I/usr/include` added as a compiler flag in the Makefile or else `make` fails because it can't find certain header files.

I don't want to have to edit the supplied Makefile, but rather pass in the `-I/usr/include` to `./configure` in my own bash script which builds several other drivers..

I've tried both of the following with `./configure`

```
--includedir=DIR       C header files [PREFIX/include]
--oldincludedir=DIR    C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
```

`DIR` replaced with `/usr/include`

Both times the build fails, but if I add `-I/usr/include` to `EXTRA_CFLAGS` in the makefile, then the `make` runs successfully.

Is it possible to supply `make` or `configure` with the include directory so I don't have to edit the third party makefile? Or am I just missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a standard autoconf package then the user (you) owns the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, *and* `CPPFLAGS` (the *CPP* here stands for *C preprocessor*, not *C++*) variables so you can modify them as you like.  For example, either of these should do what you want:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include'
```

or:

```
make CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include'
```

Comment: Also, the reason why `--includedir` didn't work is because this is where to install header files. Not where to find them.